# rails build association from the polymorphic belongs_to object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a polymorphic relation as follows:

```
class Profile
  belongs_to :practice, polymorphic: :true
end

class ForeclosurePractice
  has_one :profile, as: :practice
end
```

I want to build a practice object based on the profile I have, but unfortunately practice returns nil:

```
p = Profile.new
p.practice # => nil
```

How can I build the practice object from the Profile object?

Answer (score 5):

`p.build_practice` won't work, because the [build_other method is not generated for polymorphic associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).

If you want a way to dynamically create an instance, for example based on a class name selected in a form, you can try to use [safe_constantize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-safe_constantize) - simple example:

```
p.practice = params[:practice_type].safe_constantize.new
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on Matt's answer I would adjust the `build_practice` method like this:

I ran into the issue that updating the polymorphic `practice` would create a new object instead. (Because build_practice always calls. new.

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  def build_practice(params)
    if practice.present?
      practice.assign_attributes(params)
    else
      self.practice = practice_type.classify.constantize.new(params)
    end
  end
```

First, I was only using the second part and would wonder that it creates a new record with every update.

Answer (score -1):

You need to explicitly build the association:

```rb
p = Profile.new
p.build_practice
```

See: http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/belongs_to

Comment: Is there any drawback to doing this in the view on something like `<%= f.simple_fields_for :practice, @p.practice || @p.build_practice do |builder| %>` as it accomplishes the same thing (it would seem).

Comment: Building anything in the view is generally not the best idea. If you can avoid it, you should avoid it.

Comment: This unfortunately is not working: profile.respond_to? :build_practice # => false. The reason why build_ doesn't exist is because this is a polymorphic relation. Hence my question

Comment: You are right. I was pretty sure this would work for polymorphic relation if you give it a proper type. In that case I'm afraid only `p.practice = SomePractice.new` is the way to go.